# HTML, Set input to add additional parameters

Tags: html, input

I got input field near my pagination that let you type to required page, The problem is that when the page number you asked is submitted it erase the parameters was already embedded to the url, I will explain:

**Current parameter:**

```
somewebpage.org?xparam=5
```

**This is my form:**

```
<form method="get" action=""><input type="submit"><input type="text" name="page"></form>
```

**#1 try to keep the parameter after submission**

```
somewebpage.org?xparam=5&page=3
```

**Now i did try to do:**

```
<form method="get" action="?xparam=5"><input type="submit"><input type="text" name="page">
```

**No result, #2 try to keep the parameter after submission**

```
<form method="get" action="&xparam=5"><input type="submit"><input type="text" name="page">
```

**And the url became: somewebpage.org&xparam=5?page=3**

Does anyone know a way to set the input to add the parameter as additional or any other solution.

Comment: Add all the parameters you want to keep but don't want to display to the user as hidden fields.

Comment: When using `method="get"` you can't have parameters in the URL, because the browser won't merge parameters from the form into them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hidden field and store the value of xparam there, as shown below (in case of jsp).

```
<input type="hidden" name="xparam" value="${xparam}"
```

This way, your xparam value will be preserved. There is no need to change the action attribute of form.

Comment: Thank you Darshan, Very creative solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your form action try to add some full URL not only perameters.